# file copy from puppet master to agent fails

Tags: puppet

I am trying to do a simple file copy from puppet master to agent.

```
  [root@****************** manifests]# cat site.pp

    file {'/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh':
    source => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/my_bash_script.sh",
    mode => '755',
    }
```

please find the error.

```
 [root@ip-***********/]# puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for ip-10-20-1-137.dev.uberops.net
Info: Applying configuration version '1472255014'
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/File[my_bash_script.sh]: Could not evaluate: 
Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s)   
puppet:///modules/mymodule/my_bash_script.sh
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.06 seconds
```

Can anyone please tell me what i am missing here.

Comment: From the questions you have been asking thus far, I am assuming you are using puppet 3.6-3.8. Is that true?

Comment: yes i am using puppet 3.8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s)`
This error shows that , puppet is not able to find the file you pacified.
Please double check for the path you are providing and for file is present there.

General file structure is as like:

`-/etc/puppet
-/etc/puppet/manifest/
-/etc/puppet/files
-/etc/puppet/modules`

If you have setup your module directory somewhere else (/modules/mymodule/files/your-file-here) then your path to file would be;
`puppet:///modules-directory/modules-name/file-name` i.e `puppet:///modules/mymodule/your-file-here`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on Puppet >= 3.7, you need to be using directory environments for your own modules. The `/etc/puppet/modules/` directory, or `$basemodulepath`, is for base modules such as stdlib, lvm, etc. that are not declared, but rather have types, functions, etc. that are referenced.

Move your module from `/etc/puppet/modules/` to your client's appropriate directory environment at `/etc/puppet/environments/'environment'/modules` to fix your issue.

Additional info:

For Puppet Enterprise 3.8, this would be at `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/'environment'/modules`. For Puppet 4 Enterprise and non-Enterprise, this would be at `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/'environment'/modules`.

With the default directory environment of production, this would be at `/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules` for your case.

Comment: There's rather too much style over substance for me in this answer.  The base module path is for modules that are to be shared across environments.  The *nature* of such modules is a question of site requirements and policy.  There's no particular reason why modules stored there should not contain classes that are referenced from user manifests, nor why site-local modules should not reside there.  Indeed, I'm not immediately seeing why the proposed change should be expected to solve the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger His previous question indicated he had the module in `/etc/puppet/modules` and this is a version of Puppet that requires directory environments.

Comment: I'm still not seeing your point.  Directory environments do not preclude modules being shared across environments, and they do not impose restrictions on what kind of modules can be so shared.  Such a restriction as you describe is at most a matter of policy, not a technical limitation.  If the OP's module is already in his `$basemodulepath`, as seems to be the case, then I see no reason to believe that his problem would be solved by moving it.

Answer (score 1):

The URL `puppet:///modules/mymodule/my_bash_script.sh` corresponds to a file `mymodule/files/my_bash_script.sh` relative to the applicable module path.  That file must exist and be readable by the master  / puppetserver process.  Probably the most common problems that produce the kind of error you present are

- you've misspelled the file name
- you've put the file in the wrong directory
- the ownership / permissions / ACL / SELinux context and policy do not permit the master to read the file